# Gunicorn worker getting restarted itself after long API calls

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, uwsgi

I have a flask application which is running using Gunicorn.

This flask application have an API which takes two hours to complete.

If the same API is called twice after a 30 minutes gap between two , then the process handling the first API call is getting restarted after the second API call.

Example:
Initial process starts with API_1
After 30 mins API_1 is called again , then the process handling previous API_1 call is getting restarted.

Command used to start the Gunicorn server:

```
nohup gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=8 run:app --timeout 7200  --preload> output.log&
```

No of core : 8

I am not facing any issue while running flask in development mode.

Any idea why its behaving like this ?

Comment: gunicorn is managing the worker processes. Restarting them as needed is part of the process.

Comment: is it possible to prevent the restart of worker if it is not idle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other types of worker. Your current worker type is sync. If you want to send a long request probably you must use a thread worker or async worker.

```
nohup gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -k gevent run:app
```

Refer to this [document](https://medium.com/@genchilu/brief-introduction-about-the-types-of-worker-in-gunicorn-and-respective-suitable-scenario-67b0c0e7bd62)